# What function to use with this timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, java, timestamp

I have timestamp (stored as BIGINT) format I cannot turn into a human-readable format:

```
1462975819250
```

It points to a date in 2016-may-11th. However function to_timestamp() turns this into:

```
48329-11-10 13:00:49.999872+01
```

I'd like to create a VIEW where I could display these values, don't know what function to use.

The field is written by a Java program (EclipseLink I presume). I don't have the source-code of the program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`to_timestamp()` expects the parameter to be given in seconds. Your value is in miliseconds. Just divide it by 1000:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1462975819.250);
```

gives `2016-05-11 16:10:19.25+02`

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you are storing milliseconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00` so Adam's answer is right. Another way would be to use interval addition to the `'epoch'` timestamp (which is `1970-01-01 00:00:00`):

```
select timestamptz 'epoch' + 1462975819250 * interval '1 millisecond' 
       as my_timestamp ;
```

Tested:

```
test=# select timestamptz 'epoch' + 1462975819250 * interval '1 millisecond' 
              as my_timestamp ;
       my_timestamp        
---------------------------
 2016-05-11 15:10:19.25+01
(1 row)
```

Adams:

```
test=# select to_timestamp(1462975819250 / 1000.0) ;
       to_timestamp        
---------------------------
 2016-05-11 15:10:19.25+01
(1 row)
```

the `'epoch'` timestamp:

```
test=# select timestamptz 'epoch' as the_start_of_times;
   the_start_of_times   
------------------------
 1970-01-01 01:00:00+01
(1 row)
```

(The 1-hour diff and the `+1` are because my local settings are in UTC+1.)

And from the related Jaca docs [Class Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html):

> **`getTime`**
>
> `public long getTime()`
>
> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
>   represented by this Timestamp object.
>
> **Overrides**:
>       `getTime` in class `Date`
>
> **Returns**:
>     the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this date.
>
> See Also:
>     `setTime(long)`